# What should I do if there's a mistake in my textbook regarding anatomy?

Tags: publications

Some information in my college level Anatomy and Physiology textbook is about a decade (if not more) out of date? The information does not only cause a lack of understanding, but also encourages a misunderstanding.

What should I do? If I contact the publisher, how should I do it?

I'd prefer not to give specifics, as this is a fairly popular publisher.

P.S: I included "book-recommendation" as a tag as it was the most appropriate tag available.

Comment: *I'd prefer not to give specifics, as this is a fairly popular publisher.* I don't understand why this is a concern. People give errata lists all the time (in published book reviews, and even in amazon.com reviews), at least in mathematics they do. Maybe it's different in biology?

Comment: @DaveLRenfro It's not unusual in biology either. It's not the same but I found an error in a pre-print (? it was a proof that people were treating like a preprint) of a textbook and corresponded directly with the authors about it, and they fixed it in the published version.